# Group by one field and then group the result by another field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Query that Groups by a column which is needed so I get the result that I need, and then I need to return results which should be done by Grouping the previous results by another field.
So basically I have a Survey table,

```
 sql = SELECT * FROM Survey S 
       WHERE S.UserId = 79 
       Group By S.SurveyNumber 
       Having SUM (S.Counter) <> 0 ORDER BY S.SubmittedDate DESC
```

This returns the Survey grouped by the Number, and then I need to Group the result by SurveyName and return the Last Submitted Survey for that SurveyName ( Max(submittedDate). 
Can I achieve this in using one query ? If I have

```
 GroupBy S.SurveyNumber, S.SurveyName
```

Then it will try to find that have BOTH of the columns same.
How do I do this ?

Comment: `WHERE S.Id = 79` should return exactly one record (the one with ID 79), so wha the `GROUP BY S.SurveyNumber`? That makes no sense.

Comment: Ah that's UserID, which means a user can have multiple Surveys.
Not SurveyID , I apologize.

Comment: `SELECT blah FROM (SELECT foo FROM bar GROUP BY foo) AS subquery GROUP BY blah`?

Comment: What you are doing is wrong. You are selecting all records for user 79. Then you group by `SurveyNumber`, but you `select *`. That tells the DBMS: from the records for user 79 give me some `counter`, some `SubmittedDate`, etc., because you don't specify which `Counter` and which `SubmittedDate` (e.g. the minimum, maximumn, etc.). `Having SUM (S.Counter) <> 0` works, though, because you are using `SUM`; you'll only keep `SurveyNumber` with a sum that does not equal zero. Then you order your rows (remember they have arbitrarily picked `SubmittedDate`) by date, which is completely random.

Comment: I suggest you tell us what you want to achieve. How are users, survey numbers and survey names related? And show some sample data and expected results please.

Comment: A user has multiple surveys.
I initially had a query that would return Surveys for a user and` GroupBy S.SurveyNumber and Sum(S.Counter)<>0` would ensure  that I get distinct Paid surveys.
Now I have to return Distinct Paid Surveys but grouped By the SurveyName and I need to get the Last submitted Survey for it.
So the expected results is Distinct paid surveys information grouped by SurveyName returning the rows with last submittedDate for the surveyName.
I apologize i wasn't clear enough earlier. @ThorstenKettner

Comment: @EzraS can't you just group by SurveyName?

Comment: Once I'm grouping By SurveyNumber,
Then how do I group by SurveyName ? That was my initial question. Do I write it as a subquery as suggested ? I'm a beginner so I wasn't sure about the best/proper way to do this. @AlexZen

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me to group by two times. Is SurveyNumber a primary key? Maybe what you want is just to group by SurveyNumber, and then show the SurveyName? In this case, you'd just need to group by SurveyNumber, and the SELECT min(SurveyName), because you would have only one Surveyname for each Surveynumber

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understand this:

1. Every survey belongs to one user. You want the survey of one particular user.
2. The table is actually not a *Survey* table (with one record representing a survey), but a kind of *survey chronology* table. There are multiple records per survey.
3. You must look at all records per survey in order to know whether its paid.
4. For each paid survey you want the last chronology record.

You have already shown how to check whether a survey is paid. Now select the last date for them (the maximum date). Based on this get the related records from the table.

```
select *
from survey
where (surveynumber, submitteddate) in
(
  select surveynumber, max(submitteddate)
  from survey
  where userid = 79 
  group by surveynumber 
  having sum(counter) <> 0 
);
```

I may be wrong though, because you make it sound like a survey number is somehow independent from the survey name. (One survey number with various names? The same survey name for multiple survey numbers?)

You would certaily benefit from a better data model with at least two separate tables for survey and survey details.

Answer (score 0):

i think it works:

```
SELECT 
    S2.SurveyName
    ,SUM(S2.Count) as SurveyCount

FROM ( 
    select 
        SUM(S.SurveyNumber) as Count
        ,S.SurveyName 
    FROM Survey S 
    where S.SurveyNumber <> 0 
    Group By S.SurveyNumber,S.SurveyName 
) as S2

Group By S2.SurveyName
```